# Formulario HTML y PHP

Tags: php, html

Buen dia, recien estoy empezando con el desarrollo web y se me ocurrio meter mano en php, con tutoriales, etc. El problema que estoy teniendo es el siguiente:
Tengo un formulario html que quiero enviar por correo mediante un archivo php externo. Logré que me anvié todos los datos menos los del checkbox.

Este es el check que no me muestra:

```
<label for="atenc" class="form_contact"><input type="checkbox" id="Atenc" class="" name="Atenc" value="Atenciones">INSERTAR ATENCIONES</label>
```

Los valores del form los estaba tomando en el PHP asi:

```
$especialidad = $_POST['Especialidad'];
$uso = $_POST['Uso'];
$atenciones = $_POST['Atenc'];
```

Si me pueden dar una mano estaré realmente agradecido.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask] para orientarte y mejorar tu pregunta. Para enviar correo con **formato html** puedes consultar el **ejemplo #4** en la documentación oficial de php -en español- [función mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail)

Comment: El valor se esta enviando en el request que haces al servidor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los checkboxes funcionan de una manera especial al ser enviados. Si no estan chequeados, no se envia el valor (asi que `$_POST['Atenc']` no existira y dara un warning en PHP por no existir el indice)

Si deseas que siempre envie la variable con un valor inicial (vacio por ejemplo) en caso de no ser chequeada, usa un input hidden con igual nombre antes del checkbox:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="Atenc" value=""><!-- enviar valor Atenc="" si no es chequeado--> 
<input type="checkbox" id="Atenc" class="" name="Atenc" value="Atenciones">
<label for="Atenc" class="form_contact">INSERTAR ATENCIONES</label>
```

Por otra parte, puedes manejar la no-existencia de una variable en el lado de PHP usando un valor por defecto en caso de que no se envie el valor:

```
$atenciones = @$_POST['Atenc'] ?: "";
```

EN este caso @ impide que lance un warning por no existir el indice, y `?:` es una version el operador ["ternario"](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) que equivale a

```
if (is_set($_POST["Atenc"])) $atenciones = $_POST['Atenc']; else $atenciones = "";
```

Comment: No es buena idea silenciar errores o advertencias, eso le permitirá al usuario conocer que esta fallando